# Google Apps Script - optional chaining throwing ParseError

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, optional-chaining

Why doesn't google Apps Script support latest javascript features like optional chaining even though it's running on Chrome V8? When optional chaining is used, clasp is throwing an error.

`GaxiosError: Syntax error: ParseError: Unexpected token .`

The runtime environment is already mentioned in the manifest file `appsscript.json` as:

```
{
    ...
    "runtimeVersion": "V8",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optional chaining now works.

---

<s>Currently, this feature(optional chaining) is not supported. [A bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155146773#comment3) was raised and was denied by Google:</s>

> Status: Won't Fix (Infeasible)
> Hello, Currently this operator does not work on Apps Script.
> V8 allows you to run modern syntax, but not all of the newly released features. You can check the information in ⁠V8 Runtime Overview
> To sum up, apps script v8 is not javascript.
> Regards.

You may however be able to raise a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) for the same(This is NOT a bug report).

Comment: Is there an eslint setting that matches what the V8 runtime supports?

Comment: @Steve `"ecmaVersion": 6` should satisfy. You could also try `2018` or `2019`  instead of `6`